# How do I prevent re-flashing of my PCIe FPGA card rebooting my computer?

Tags: pci-express

I'm working with an FPGA PCIe card. I'm customizing the reference design which includes, in addition to my own code, support for PCIe communication.

Every time I flash the card, this causes a power cycle, which gets the computer (running Windows Server 2019) to panic and reboot. I don't want this.

The exact error is `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power`, no further information is available.

I know PCIe is not plug-and-play, but I was wondering if there's any way to disconnect-reconnect-reinitialize a PCIe peripheral.

Comment: What OS? Linux? Is the system genuinely panicking?... perhaps because the driver crashed (because the device just disappeared)? Is the system resetting because of a power supply issue? Can you share more info? PCIe does support hotplugging... so long as the driver doesn't freak out.

Comment: @Attie Win 2019 Server, added info to question.

Comment: What is the suggested method of flashing the card?  I can't imagine the recommended method is to flash while the OS is actively using the card.

Comment: “I know PCIe is not plug-and-play,” It is though? It can even do hot-plug, which is probably what you were actually referring to. So there must be a mistake somewhere in your PCIe communication. // Also, the event log you’re referring to probably just saying “Yeah, PC crashed”. Not that helpful.